# Handling multiple tables using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I am checking the folder hierarchy on a webpage, depending on the type of user. User1 has a set of permissions which enable him to see the folder structure like this :

```
Main Folder
    - First Child
        -First Grandchild
        -Second Grandchild
    - Second Child
    - Third Child
```

Each branch of the tree is a table consisting of 1 row. But the number of columns varies depending on the generation.

The "Main Folder" parent has only 1 column. The cell content is the string "Main Folder".

The children branches have 2 columns, the first cell containing blank space, and the next cell containing the name of the branch ("First Child", "Second Child").

The grandchildren branches have 3 columns, the first and second cell containing blank space, and the the third cell containing the name of the branch (" First Grandchild", "Second Grandchild").

HTML code :

```
<div id = 0>
    <div id = 1>
    <table id = 1>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="content1" 
                <a id="label1" 
                <span id="treeNode1"  
                Main Folder
                </span>
                </a>
           </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

            <div id = 2>
            <table id = 2>
            <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>    
                    <td id="content2" 
                        <a id="label2" 
                        <span id="treeNode2"  
                            First Child 
                        </span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
           </tbody>
           </table>

                    <div id = 5>
                    <table id = 5>
                    <tbody>
                         <tr>
                            <td>
                            <td>
                            <td id="content5" 
                                <a id="label5" 
                                <span id="treeNode5"  
                                    First GrandChild 
                                </span>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            </td>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </div>

                    <div id = 6>
                    <table id = 6>
                    <tbody>
                         <tr>
                            <td>
                            <td>
                            <td id="content6" 
                                <a id="label6" 
                                <span id="treeNode6"  
                                    Second GrandChild 
                                </span>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            </td>
                            </td>
                       </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div> /* End of division 2 */


            <div id = 3>
            <table id = 3>
            <tbody>
                 <tr>
                        <td>
                        <td id="content3" 
                            <a id="label3" 
                            <span id="treeNode3"  
                                Second Child 
                            </span>
                            </a>
                       </td>
                       </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>


            <div id = 4>
            <table id = 4>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                        <td>
                        <td id="content4" 
                            <a id="label4" 
                            <span id="treeNode4"  
                                Third Child 
                            </span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>

    </div> /*End of division 1 */
</div> /* End of division 0 */
```

User2 has a different set of permissions, which enable him to see the folder structure like this :

```
Main Folder
    - First Child
        -First Grandchild
    - Second Child
    - Third Child
```

The corresponding table is absent in the html code for this user.

My test case is to check User2 doesn't have access to the second grandchild. This means I need to ensure that particular table doesn't exist on the webpage.

How can I check this in selenium ? I am using JUnit for my test cases. I want to do an "assert" to ensure the second grandchild is not present.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to check to see if the element is not present or not visible. Calling `isElementVisible()` inside an assert false should do the trick. Just get the By locator of the elements you want to check.

```
private boolean isElementVisible(By by)
{
    try
    {
        return driver.findElement(by).isDisplayed();
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this.

Comment: Hmm would be better to return false outside the catch block in case where element is not visible but is found.

Comment: @Karthik If the element is found and not visisble isDisplayed() will return false.